# How could I check if string is only match into an other string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm actually a beginner into web developpment.

I have a problem with my actual condition.

Exemple :

```
$rooms = 10;
```

In my code, I check if $rooms is equal to 1,0 or 10 so :

```
if(strpos($rooms, '1')){echo 1;}
if(strpos($rooms, '0')){echo 0};
if(strpos($rooms, '10')){echo 10;}
```

My result :

```
1
0
10
```

My condition match for 1, 0 and 10, where I only need to match the number 10

How can I only pass into my third condition ?

Thx

Comment: You want to check if the string is an exact match?

Comment: which language?

Comment: What deos it have in common with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Ben Lonsdale Yes

Comment: @RohanKumar I see, but it's tagged so, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @ Arkej Its because I used select2 to preselect my actual select, but I rewrite my question without delete jquery and javascript tag, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex, and surrounding the word with `\b` word boundary

> preg_match("~\bMures\b~",$string)

example:

```
$rooms = '10';
if ( preg_match("~\b10\b~",$rooms) )
   echo "matched";
else
   echo "no match";
```

Comment: What about for -1 match ? Something like \b-?-1\b ?

Answer (score 1):

use `if($rooms=='10'){echo 10;}` to check if it is equal

Comment: My $rooms is a string who can contain 1, 0 and 10, separeted by comma

Answer (score 1):

You can see from php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) that `strpos` is just getting you the index of a substring in a string.

If you want to comepare string just use compare string functions:

```
if (strcmp($var1, $var2) == 0) echo 'we are equal';
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) you should check the documentation of string compare.

Answer (score 1):

Compare it with "===", but I would suggest another approach for better readability: Use the switch statement. This is especially useful when you get more comparisons in the future.:

```
switch ($rooms) {
    case '0':
        echo "0";
        break;
    case '1':
        echo "1";
        break;
    case '10':
        echo "10";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thx @hallleron, but I forgot to specify that my $rooms is a string who can contain "1,0,10" in a row

Comment: Ah okay sorry I didn't realize this ... sounds like regex time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) (strict/non-strict mode as third parameter) like,

```
$arr = array(1,0,10);
var_dump(in_array(0,$arr));
var_dump(in_array(22,$arr));
var_dump(in_array(10,$arr));
var_dump(in_array(1,$arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
$rooms === ('your number') ? echo '(your number)' : echo '(else)';
```

change 'your number' with any number u like.
change echo '(else)' with anything u want if the condition is not met
or leave just '' after a colon for nothing to happen

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($rooms, '10')>= 0){echo 10;}
elseif(strpos($rooms, '1')>= 0){echo 1;}
elseif(strpos($rooms, '0')>= 0){echo 0;}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.